# Exporting db table from SQL Server 2008 R2 to Excel 2007

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

SQL Server 2008 R2 (management tool, not coding as I'm a bit of a noob) to Excel.

I need to export info from my db table *COMPANY* (some feilds varchar(50) some nchar(10)) to an Excel spreadsheet which i just created as normal - Excel > New > Blank.

Everything seems to be straight forward but just cant see the problem... Please see below and thanks a million in advance :)

> Pre-execute (Error) Messages Error 0xc0202009: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS
>   Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR. An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code:
>   0x80040E21. (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> Error 0xc0202025: Data Flow Task 1: Cannot create an OLE DB accessor.
>   Verify that the column metadata is valid. (SQL Server Import and
>   Export Wizard)
>
> Error 0xc004701a: Data Flow Task 1: component "Destination - COMPANY"
>   (37) failed the pre-execute phase and returned error code 0xC0202025.
>   (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> ```
> Executing (Warning) Messages Warning: Preparation SQL Task 1: Multiple-step OLE DB
> ```
>
> operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB
>   status value, if available. No work was done. (SQL Server Import and
>   Export Wizard)
>
> Warning: Preparation SQL Task 1: Multiple-step OLE DB operation
>   generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No
>   work was done. (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> ```
> Copying to COMPANY (Stopped)
>
> Post-execute (Stopped) Messages Information 0x4004300b: Data Flow Task 1: "component "Destination - COMPANY" (37)" wrote 0 rows. (SQL
> ```
>
> Server Import and Export Wizard)

Comment: did u try a select * from the table and simply copy and paste the results?

Comment: it seems to be some strange bug in SSIS or in MS SQL Management studio, and you know what... it always happens with table COMPANY. Exactly like in your case. I excluded this table from export, all other tables went fine. May be "Company" is some not allowed hardcoded parameter :)

Answer (score 2):

When you're in the import wizard, at the point you've selected the table or view to export, click the [Edit Mappings] button. What solved my problem was to change the fields with an export data type of "Long Text" to "VarChar" 255 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Your source table might contain some column with NVARCHAR data type that’s why you are getting this error.

It’s not good solution still i will give try to change data type of column from NVARCHAR TO VARCHAR.

Thanks
Dhiraj